# Specify only 'numPartitions' options for spark DataFrameReader

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Specify only option `numPartitions` without `partitionColumn`,`lowerBound`,`upperBound` in  for spark [DataFrameReader.jdbc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#jdbc(url:String,table:String,properties:java.util.Properties):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) always generates only 1 partition.

To reproduce, I've made a github repo https://github.com/sammyne/spark-mysql-partitioning-demo, where the application goes as [HelloWorldMySQL.scala](https://github.com/sammyne/spark-mysql-partitioning-demo/blob/main/src/main/scala/HelloWorldMySQL.scala).

Is it designed as so? Or have I make some mistake while using the API?

Really appreciate if someone could help me out ~

Answer (score 1):

Spark jdbc docu: [Spark docu](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)

description of parameters from the docu:

> numPartitions - The maximum number of partitions that can be used for parallelism in
> table reading and writing. This also determines the maximum number of
> concurrent JDBC connections. If the number of partitions to write
> exceeds this limit, we decrease it to this limit by calling
> coalesce(numPartitions) before writing.
>
> partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound   (none)  (These options must
> all be specified if any of them is specified.)
>
> In addition,
> numPartitions must be specified. They describe how to partition the
> table when reading in parallel from multiple workers. partitionColumn
> must be a numeric, date, or timestamp column from the table in
> question. Notice that lowerBound and upperBound are just used to
> decide the partition stride, not for filtering the rows in table. So
> all rows in the table will be partitioned and returned. This option
> applies only to reading.  read

On read numPartitions is not used to repartition the data when they are already loaded into memory but it is used for max parallelism during read.

For Spark to be able to read query in parallel you need to provide partitionColumn and lower/upper bound, otherwise Spark dont know how to split table to be able to load it in parallel.

All Spark can do is such situation is to create query like select * from table which cannot be run in parallel on many executors thus you end up with single partition

If you cant use lower/upper bounds you can repartition your dataset manually after read